# Tensorflow using float64 tensor

Tags: tensorflow, finite-precision

I have a feed-forward neural network with a customized cost function. Since my cost function has an exponential component,  I need to handle very large numbers. By default, tensorflow uses float32 datatype, which is not sufficient for my work. How can I have a tensorflow model with float64 datatype? I have tried to define all the tensors as float64 and hope the casting take care of the rest but it does not work.
Also, I have enabled the eager execution mode.

Comment: Are you using a GPU? I believe only the top-end (expensive) Nvidia GPUs will support... The V100 I believe could do it. Maybe read their website to check what's possible with your hardware.

Comment: No, I am just using CPU but my model is not very big. Isn't it a matter of memory consumption?